# PHP get last occurrence between range (strrpos)

Tags: php, function

How could i get last occurrence of symbol between some range ?

`strrpos($text, '.', 100)` it gives me last occurrence starting from 100 to the end

but how get last occurrence between some range, like:

`strrpos($text, '.', 100-250)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

`strrpos(substr($text', 100, 250), '.');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mix with strrpos and substr like `strrpos(substr($text, 100, 250), '.')`

Comment: OfirH wrote the same 1 minute after you, but thank you as well :)